# Should this question still be closed as off topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, closing-questions

The question:
[Why was Firefly cancelled?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28676/why-was-firefly-cancelled)

I've been here a while, and I can't for the life of me see why this would be considered off-topic by modern (2015) standards.   It was closed in 2012.

Comment: no idea why that was closed, none of the comments are helpful. The one comment, that it's "about a production issue" is called out in the help center as explicitly on-topic.

Answer (score 4):

**It should be reopened**. It clearly fits into the category of "*Behind-the-scenes and fandom information*" which would be very heavily on-topic by 2015 standards.

It's already at 4 reopen votes. I look forward to seeing it open again shortly.

Comment: it's open. you're welcome.